# How to do efficient reverse foreign key check on Django multi-table inheritance model?

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I've got file objects of different types, which inherit from a BaseFile, and add custom attributes, methods and maybe fields. The BaseFile also stores the File Type ID, so that the corresponding subclass model can be retrieved from any BaseFile object:

```
class BaseFile(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True)
    size= models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    file_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class FileType1(BaseFile):
    storage_path = '/path/for/filetype1/'

    def custom_method(self):
        <some custom behaviour>

class FileType2(BaseFile):
    storage_path = '/path/for/filetype2/'

    extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

I also have different types of events which are associated with files:

```
class FileEvent(models.Model):

    file = models.ForeignKey(BaseFile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I want to be able to efficiently get all files of a particular type which have not been involved in a particular event, such as:

```
unprocessed_files_type1 = FileType1.objects.filter(fileevent__isnull=True)
```

However, looking at the SQL executed for this query:

> SELECT "app_basefile"."id", "app_basefile"."name", "app_basefile"."size", "app_basefile"."time_created", "app_basefile"."file_type_id", "app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id"
>   FROM "app_filetype1"
>   INNER JOIN "app_basefile"
>   ON("app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id" = "app_basefile"."id")
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_fileevent" ON (**"app_basefile"."id" = "app_fileevent"."file_id"**)
>   WHERE "app_fileevent"."id" IS NULL

It looks like this might not be very efficient because it joins on BaseFile.id instead of FileType1.basefile_ptr_id, so it will check ALL BaseFile ids to see whether they are present in FileEvent.file_id, when I only need to check the BaseFile ids corresponding to FileType1, or FileType1.basefile_ptr_ids.

This could result in a significant performance difference if there are a very large number of BaseFiles, but FileType1 is only a small subset of that, because it will be doing a large amount of unnecessary lookups.

Is there a way to force Django to join on "app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id" or otherwise achieve this functionality more efficiently?

Thanks for the help

UPDATE:
Using annotations and Exists subquery seems to do what I'm after, however the resulting SQL still appears strange:

```
unprocessed_files_type1 = FileType1.objects.annotate(file_event=Exists(FileEvent.objects.filter(file=OuterRef('pk')))).filter(file_event=False)
```

> SELECT "app_basefile"."id", "app_basefile"."name", "app_basefile"."size", "app_basefile"."time_created", "app_basefile"."file_type_id", "app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id", 
>     EXISTS(
>       SELECT U0."id", U0."file_id", U0."time"
>       FROM "app_fileevent" U0
>       WHERE U0."file_id" = ("app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id"))
>     AS "file_event"
>    FROM "app_filetype1"
>    INNER JOIN "app_basefile" ON ("app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id" = "app_basefile"."id")
>    WHERE EXISTS(
>    SELECT U0."id", U0."file_id", U0."time"
>    FROM "app_fileevent" U0
>    WHERE U0."file_id" = ("app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id")) = 0

It appears to be doing the WHERE EXISTS subquery twice instead of just using the annotated 'file_event' label... Maybe this is just a Django/SQLite driver bug?

Comment: By the time the second join (in bold) is executed, you've already executed the first join on `"app_filetype1"."basefile_ptr_id" = "app_basefile"."id"`, so it shouldn't matter at all which one is used. You can test this by having the database `EXPLAIN` both queries.